# Hyperlinks with ticks axis do not work in Plotly

Tags: shiny, plotly

I changed simple text to hypertext in x ticks axis but nothing happens when I click on them in the plotly graph even if it appears "clickable" in the display.

```cpp
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(y = c(74,45,34,89,9),
                 x = c("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"))
                 
df$links <-  paste0("<a href=","www.rstudio.com",">",df$x,"</a>")


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Hyperlinks with axis ticks"),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          
          plotlyOutput("plot")
        
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      plot_ly(
        df,
        x = ~links,
        y = ~y,
        type = 'bar',
        textposition = 'inside')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there are missing quotes in your `a` tag:

replace

```
df$links <-  paste0("<a href=","www.rstudio.com",">",df$x,"</a>")
```

with

```
df$links <-  paste0("<a href=","'www.rstudio.com'",">",df$x,"</a>")
```